# Whenever I execute a bash command, I got a "awk: line 27: illegal reference to array change_array"?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, awk, command-line

As far as I test, mostly bash commands lead me to this awk warnning:

```sh
$ cd ~
awk: line 27: illegal reference to array change_array
$ ls
tmp
awk: line 27: illegal reference to array change_array
```

Append:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$PS1"
\[\e[0;32m\]\u\[\e[0m\]@\[\e[34;1m\]\h\[\e[0m\][⌛|: \[\]✗\[\]]:\[\e[0;33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;32m\] $ \[\e[0m\]
awk: line 27: illegal reference to array change_array
$ printf '%s\n' "$PROMPT_COMMAND"
pre_prompt_command; pure_prompt
awk: line 27: illegal reference to array change_array
$ trap -p DEBUG
awk: line 27: illegal reference to array change_array
```

Append:
The issue seems related to `bash-it`, as I uninstall it and no more awk warning prompt.

Append:

```
$ awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
```

Comment: There are a number of things that might be executing (/trying to execute) after each command; to find out what you have set up, run `printf '%s\n' "$PS1"`, `printf '%s\n' "$PROMPT_COMMAND"`, and `trap -p DEBUG`, and add their output to your question.

Comment: Just to mention, this question isn't strictly about programming, so it would be better to ask on [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se] instead. ([reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283161/4518341)) Not to say that it's off-topic, but it's in a [grey area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354126/4518341).

Comment: The only use of `change_array` I see in bash-it is in [themes/p4helpers.theme.bash](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/blob/master/themes/p4helpers.theme.bash); line 27 of the awk script uses `length(change_array)` to get the number of elements in the array, which is not supported in all versions of awk. See the last paragraph under `length([string])` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), and the `length(array)` entry [here](http://awk.freeshell.org/AwkFeatureComparison). You apparently have a version that doesn't support it.

Comment: OP is running `mawk` (and a really old version at that - Nov 1996?); I'd recommend OP gets `gawk` (`GNU awk`) installed, make sure `awk --version` shows `GNU awk` (ie, `awk` is no longer == `mawk`), and see if this gets rid of the issue